# Does a bounded countably infinite union of sets with volume have volume?

Tags: analysis, volume

If $ A_1, A_2,...$ are sets with volume and $A= \cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ is a bounded set, must $A$ have volume?

This was a homework problem that we went over in class, and if I remember correctly the answer was: no. However, I'm having some trouble coming up with a counter example. I think the idea is to have it so that $\partial A$ does not have measure zero, and $A = \mathbb {Q} \cap [0,1]$ comes to mind, but then each of the $A_i$ may not have volume.

Comment: What do you mean by "$A$ has volume"? Do you mean it is measurable? If so, then countable union of measurable sets is measurable.

Comment: If you are working with Lebesgue integral, then the answer is obviously yes. If you are working with Riemann integral, then the answer is obviously no.

Comment: I mean that the characteristic function of $A$ is Riemann integrable. @Crostul, can you please explain why?

Comment: @KevinSheng look at the answer below. You were almost done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From context it sounds like you are talking about Jordan measure. In this case the answer to your question is no; this is one of the major reasons analysts tend to prefer the Lebesgue measure over the Jordan measure.

You are already on the right track for building a counterexample. Consider $\{ q_i \}_{i=1}^\infty$ an enumeration of $A=\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$, then consider $A_i=\{ q_i \}$. Now $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ is not Jordan measurable, which you could prove by noting that $1_{\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]}$ is nowhere continuous. By contrast $A_i$ are Jordan measurable, which you could prove by noting that $1_{A_i}$ is continuous except at one point. Other proofs are available; which one is convenient for you depends on how your definitions are stated and what theorems you have already established.

Comment: So "Jordan measurable" is another way of saying "has volume"? I did not run across this in class but it's good to know!

Comment: @KevinSheng "Jordan measurable" is the technical term. "Has volume" is a perfectly good term if you have already defined it, as your class presumably did. However, it is a rather bad term for communicating with mathematicians as a whole, because they will probably either ask you what you mean or assume that you mean "is Lebesgue measurable".